# electrical wiring from pole to house

Tags: electrical, wiring, circuit-breaker, pole

Just bought a house where electrical wires from pole first goes to detached garage. Main breaker is there in the garage. But it should be in the house. Who is responsible for this incorrect wiring. If ComEd is responsible for wiring from pole to power masts then are they also responsible for that the wires are not wired to the correct location?Should I ask them to wire correctly at no cost to me?

Comment: Who is saying the garage is incorrect?  I presume there is a subpanel in the house?

Comment: If wired according to code there's nothing inherently wrong with main panel in the garage and subpanel on the house. What is the actual problem with this other than "different from usual"?

Comment: Does the house panel have a disconnecting means (main breaker) in it? How many wires run between the house and the garage?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. We need more information; please edit into your question.

Comment: There is no main breaker in the house. Only one in the garage. manassehkatz are you saying that this is ok? How can I add a main breaker in the house? There are bunch of wires running from the garage to the house, not sure how many. But they are in big conduit only from the side of the garage. From the side of the house there are simply wires going into the ground. I am just not sure how would be the right way to do.

Comment: Where is the meter located?

Comment: The utility owns the wires from their pole to the meter, you own them from the meter onward. But the utility doesn't control where the meter is, that's up to the homeowner / builder. If you ask them to disconnect and change the location, you will likely have to pay for it.The NEC makes no requirement as to location other than accessibility for a firefighter to be able to kill power when they arrive to fight a fire, minimum height, distance from other objects etc.